# 500 Internal Server Error when raising ValidationError in production

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible. I have a custom field:

```
class CharExactLengthField(CharField):
    """ FormField to represent a CharField with an exact Length
    """
    def __init__(self, length=None, required=True, widget=None, label=None,
                 initial=None):
        self.length = length
        CharField.__init__(self, max_length=length, required=required,
                                 widget=widget, label=label, initial=initial)
    def clean(self, value):
        """ Clean for CharExactLengthField
        """
        super(CharExactLengthField, self).clean(value)
        if not self.required and value in EMPTY_VALUES:
            return None
        if self.length != len(value):
            raise ValidationError(
                'Require exactly %i characters' % self.length)
        return value
```

This field is being used in several forms, but in this specific form I'm just testing if this field is empty or not, so it will fallback to `super(CharExactLengthField, self).clean(value)`. While testing this in development I get the normal `This field is required`:

[image]

When I test the same thing in production I get an `Internal Server Error`:

```
ValidationError at /test/test/1/
[u'This field is required.']

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://smo/test/test/1/
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    [u'This field is required.']
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/newforms/fields.py in clean, line 78
```

Is there any reason why this could be happening? Why is a `ValidationError` throwing an Internal Server Error only in production?

**Note:**

If you haven't noticed already, this is Django **0.96.5**

Comment: I assume the codebase you're working on cannot upgrade to a newer Django version ?

Comment: @SteveK No, at least not at the moment. Migrating the code will take more time and effort than maintaining it

Comment: Checking the web server logs may help for 500 related errors. In production it may fail at any other case not raising `ValidationError` at all.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?